# Unexpected results using js to remove divs from dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to remove all divs in a parent div with a button using .remove.

Only even number divs in div array are removed?

Conditions:
1. There is a  div with id projects

2. In the projects div there isa  variable number of other divs each one containing only a small icon type graphic?
3. These divs have given ids in the sequence "part0","part6","part12",etc
4. I have a button that calls the function below in an effort to clear all images/divs at once.

The actual result is that all even divs are removed on first button click (part0,part2,etc).

On each subsequent button click half of the remaining divs are removed.

```
function getDivs()
{
var containerDiv = document.getElementById("project");
var innerDivs = containerDiv.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
for(var i=0; i<innerDivs.length; i++)
{var r=innerDivs[i].id;
var elem = document.getElementById(r);
elem.remove();
}
```

Example 2

I thought maybe that as each div was removed the dom sequence was readjusted or the div moved up one position in the order so I tried to loop through removing the array[0] item on each pass.  Same result.
Could some one explain what is happening or a correction to the code so that all divs in the project div are deleted in one loop.

```
function getDivs()
{
var containerDiv = document.getElementById("project");
var innerDivs = containerDiv.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
for(var i=0; i<innerDivs.length; i++)
{var r=innerDivs[0].id;
var elem = document.getElementById(r);
elem.remove();
}
```

Thanks for help

Tim

Comment: It would be helpful if you use [jsfiddle.com](jsfiddle.com) to replicate your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

```js
function getDivs() {
  var containerDiv = document.getElementById("project");
  var innerDivs = containerDiv.querySelectorAll("div");
  if(innerDivs.length)
  {
    var elem = innerDivs[innerDivs.length-1];
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="project">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="getDivs()">Remove Last Div</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  Works for me!!

This is first question I have posted so not sure of mechanics,etiqette, and procedures of site. 

    

The odd results of my first attempt distracted me from the final goal which was to delete only the last created div with each button click.
Could you give me a change to your code that would remove only the last div.  You could reply privately if desired timathis@yahoo.com.
Or perhaps I should open another question?

Thanks Tim

Comment: Got it.Sorry about code formatting below. Been working on this so long I was just ready for immediate answer. Kept getting remove not a function when tried without the loop.  Using your code as a base I ended with this*****************************.function clearLast() {
  var containerDiv = document.getElementById("project");
  var innerDivs = containerDiv.querySelectorAll("div");
  var i=innerDivs.length-1;
  var elem = document.getElementById(innerDivs[i].id);
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version that tests if the parent still has childnodes to delete:

```
function getDivs(n){
    if( n && n.hasChildNodes ) while( n.childNodes.length > 0 ) n.removeChild( n.firstChild );
}
/* and call it like this */

getDivs.call( this, document.getElementById('project') );

/* or, all in one function: */

function getDivs(){
    var n=document.getElementById('project');
    if( n && n.hasChildNodes ) while( n.childNodes.length > 0 ) n.removeChild( n.firstChild );
}
/* and call like this: */
getDivs.call( this );

/* or attach as a listener on a link or button or ... */
```

Comment: Thanks .

Your answer will require me to look at the concepts involved some more.


Thanks Tim

Comment: Thanks: Definitely some new concepts for me here!!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for responses.

I made it work myself with this code:

```
function getDivs()
{
var containerDiv = document.getElementById("project");
var innerDivs = containerDiv.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
for(var i=0; i<innerDivs.length; i=i++)
{var elem = document.getElementById(innerDivs[i].id);
elem.remove();
}
}
```

Tim